# How to display products with multiple conditions, product_id and category_id

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, query-posts

I want to show all product satisfy 2 conditional are **array product id** and **array categories id** . I tried this code but it's not working

```
$args = array( 
   'post_type' => 'product', 
   'post_status' =>'publish', 
   'post__in' => array(1,2,3) 
   'tax_query' => array( 
      'relation' => 'AND', 
       array( 
          'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 
          'field' => 'id', 
          'terms' => array( 103, 115, 206 ), 
          'include_children' => false, 
          'operator' => 'IN' 
       ), 
    ) 
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Please give me some ideas ?

Comment: `$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'product',
'post_status' =>'publish',
'post__in' => array(1,2,3)
'tax_query' => array(                   
    'relation' => 'AND',                
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
        'include_children' => false,        
        'operator' => 'IN'
      ),
)

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );`

Comment: this is not an interrogation basement of the CIA ;) please put all relevant information in the question itself including expected results, actual results and whatever debuging efforts you have tried

Comment: I know it's illegal so I am looking for the solution. same my description, that's all

Comment: it is your question.... you want an answer.... code in comments is unreadable, and question is unclear so if you are not going to improve the question there is less chance you will get good answer

Comment: sorry @MarkKaplun , please look at the question. I updated it